# No Message body reader found for MultipartFormDataInput in Java Rest Service

Tags: java, rest, maven-3, resteasy, multipartform-data

I am currently working on a Java **Rest service** which consumes **multipart form data** (`Content type = "multipart/form-data"`).

I am able to consume and parse the data successfully from an IDE (Eclipse and Netbeans) but I get the error below when I build the project to a jar and run from command line/terminal.

I am building with maven.

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.InternalServerErrorException: 
Bad arguments passed to public javax.ws.rs.core.Response 
com.josephappeah.corporate.js_email_client.service.JSEmailClientService.sendEmail
(org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput) (org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException     
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: 
Could not find message body reader for type: interface org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput 
of content type: multipart/form-data;boundary="----Web KitFormBoundaryLY5W7EUGHvXNOzsJ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around by using the maven assembly plug in instead of the shade plug in.